# Problem with IBM Notes ODBC Connections not clearing out on Domino 9 server

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I support an older Lotus Notes application that uses ODBC to connect to Oracle for reading and writing purposes.  Each of the connection objects are being set to Nothing when their routine is complete, but, for some reason, Domino will not drop the connections.  This causes us to have to reboot the Domino server that application resides on every day.  Sometimes, once a day is not enough to keep the program from grinding to a near standstill.  Does anyone have any ideas how to get those connections to drop when the script is done processing?

MJ

Comment: Hi Mike: please supply your exitsing connection initiation and termination code for review (you may need to edit the original question to get it to display nicely and not wrap into an unreadable mess). Robert

Comment: Yes, show the code and give much more information. What is the Domino version, and specific ODBC driver version and the properties that are set for it? Are you using the LC LSX? Or are you using the ancient LS:DO? Or should I say "the even more ancient..." Also, I assume you are running your code as a LotusScript agent, but is it an HTTP agent or an AMGR agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the ODBC class has a disconnect method.  Who knew?  Sorry to waste everyones's time.  I put in the disconnect and problem was solved.  Not sure why I never noticed it before.  Anyway, thanks for the replies.

MJ